# Data in one component wont bind to array in injectable

Tags: data-binding, angular

I have following issue:

I have one component, in which I am calling:

```
this.users = UsersInj.getUsersCollection()
```

In `UsersInj`, I have:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersInj{
    public users:any = [];
    constructor(private _http:Http){
        this.getUsers().subscribe(
            success=>{
                this.users = success.json();
            },
            error =>{
                console.log('error')
            }
        )
    }

    getUsers(){
        return this._http.get('/api/user');
    }

    getUsersCollection(){
        console.log('GET USERS COLLECTION :',this.users);
        return this.users;
    }
}
```

However, `this.users.length` in my component is always 0. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

It works when I pack `this.users` in `UsersInj` in an object.

[**PLNKR**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qr8IueSBlqxJBQ937vzE?p=preview)

Comment: Try {{users|json}} and show us your `users`object...

Comment: It just displays '[]' in my view

Comment: Normally, in angular1, I would use angular.copy(), and it should work.

Comment: It means it doesnt receive any data. Make sure u get data through service...

Comment: In your sercive constructor check wether u get data in `users` from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the plunker you copy the values (references) once when `TheContent` is created.

```
export class TheContent {

  name: any;

  constructor(public nameService: NameService) {
    console.log("content started");
    this.info = nameService.info
    this.names = nameService.names;
  }
  changeMyName() {
    this.nameService.change();

  }
}
```

In `NameService` you assign a new array to `this.names`.

```
this.names = success.json();
```

`this.names` in `TheContent` and `this.names` in `NameService` are now not connected anymore.

What you probably want to do is

```
  change(){
    this.info.name = "Jane";
    this.http.get('https://api.github.com/repos/vmg/redcarpet/issues?state=closed').subscribe(success=>{
      while(this.names.length > 0) {
        this.names.pop();
      }
      this.names.push.apply(this.names, success.json());
      console.log('names: ' + this.names);
    });
  }
```

or alternatively copy the new array to `TheContent` again.

In Angular using an `Observable` that allows interested parties to subscribe to changes and pass the new value with the notification is the preferred way. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35568924/217408

Comment: I thought that this issue should be fixed in angualr2?

Comment: This is pretty much how it looked like in angular1: angular.copy ?

Comment: That's not related to Angular at all, that's pure JavaScript (or computer programming in general).

Comment: Could you refer to an article which would explain why is that? (just interested in why is that)

Comment: At first you pass a reference from one class to another. Now both classes reference the same array. Then you replace the reference the first class has with something entirely different. Now these two classes refer to two different arrays (one refers to the old array, one to the new). If you want both to update synchronously you must not break the connection. In my example above I did this by not replacing the reference to the array but by replacing the content of the array. Both classes see the change because they still reference the same array. This is how memory works in computers.